# Define two targets with command window

Tags: windows, command-prompt, target

I'd like to open a command window and initialize two targets:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Compiler\11.0\061\fortran\Bin\ifortvars.bat" ia32

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

I can do one at a time (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /k`) but I don't know how to do both of them at the same command window. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarcB, such as C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Compiler\11.0\061\fortran\Bin\ifortvars.bat" ia32 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86?

Comment: no. a .bat file, with `start prog1` and `start prog2` as the two commands. 'course, since you're trying to execute .bat files, you'd probably have to `call` those as well.

Comment: I've tried: `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Compiler\11.0\061\fortran\Bin\ifortvars.bat" intel64
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
start C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` but it opens for a second a command window which seems to initialize the bat files and the environment variables and then it closes and at the end it opens a standard command window. I'd like to get a command window where the two bat files were initialized as well so to set the environment variables. My skills working with bat files are very basic. sorry